# How can I permanently delete My Folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

How can I **permanently** delete the My Music, My Pictures, My Videos, etc. folders in Windows 7?

When I delete these folders manually, Windows Media Player 12 recreates all of them again, again and again! It's a nightmare. Does anyone knows a registry hack to get rid of these folders forever?

Note: I know how to disable the Libraries feature in Windows 7, but I don't want this, I want to delete only the folders named above.

Comment: Are you refering to the directory named `c:\users\<myuser>\pictures` or to the link created from that path under `c:\users\<myuser>\documents\My Pictures` ?

Comment: why do you want to delete it?

Comment: nvm why he wants to delete it. Credit him with enough intelligence for having a valid reason to ask the question - or let him suffer the consequences if not.

Comment: Yes, I'm refering to directories/folders like c:\users\me\pictures.

Comment: Free will, remember that? First of all, I want to delete because I don't use them and don't need them. I already have my music/videos/etc very well organized in my own way, do not need a software like Windows to force me into its way.

Furthermore, when I try to save something to disk, these folders appear in the first target options, unnecessarily, wasting precious space on the screen where it should be the **real** targets that **really** interest to me, always forcing me to pull down the scroll bar, without the slightest need. It really irritates me, cause it's a waste of time.

Comment: You should be advised that these are not really folders, but are instead what NTFS calls a junction.  Also deleting these is not recommended as they are used for application compatibility.

Comment: I moved mine from drive C to drive D, to isolate data from OS, using the "Location" tab built into Windows Explorer for those special folders.  In preparation to migrate to an SSD, I'm moving everything back to it's default location in C:\Users\Username\, but upon doing so, Windows locked me out of the folders on my D drive (administrator could not even take ownership).  I restarted and ran scan disk, and this time I could delete the folders, but WINDOWS JUST RECREATED THEM RIGHT IN FRONT OF MY EYES AND LOCKED ME OUT OF THEM AGAIN. Can't delete them, can't access them.  WTF.

Comment: delete the directory, then quickly, create a file with the same name and use `cacls` to revoke all rights from the user called "SYSTEM" from the file.

Comment: What is the complete list of folders that you want to delete? If `My Music`, `My Pictures` and `My Videos` is the complete list, then don't say "etc."

Answer (score 2):

I tried deleting `c:\users\<myuser>\documents\My Videos` and `c:\users\<myuser>\documents\My Pictures` and it worked fine.

However, trying to delete `c:\users\<myuser>\Pictures` and `c:\users\<myuser>\Videos` did not work, Windows Media Player did return them.

It never bothered me enough to find a "solution" for it in WMP configuration, but I might have a solution for you if you just want your music folder to be elsewhere.

I used **[Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768)**. It can create soft-links on your PC. I used it to change `c:\users\<myuser>\Music` to point to `d:\Music`. That way your music can remain in the library but from the path you like. (Notice the source and target of the link are on different partitions of the same physical drive, I do not know if it supports it on different physical drives (pretty sure it doesn't).

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your workaround tip, but I really want to delete permanently these folders and stop Windows 7 from recreate them again.

Comment: They are not folders, they are junctions, get the junction file in the above answer and run the following commands in a Command Prompt window that is running as Administrator:

junction -d "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Music"
junction -d "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Pictures"
junction -d "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Videos"

Answer (score 2):

1. Click start -> run
2. In the Open box, type regsvr32 /u mydocs.dll
3. Click OK and then click OK again to the 'DllUnregisterServer in mydocs.dll succeeded' dialog
4. Delete the My ... sub-folders that you do not want

Comment: mydocs.dll not found (windows 7 ultimate)

Comment: when I run this command on Win7, I get the error : *The module mydocs.dll is loaded but entry point DLLInstall is missing; Verify that mydocs.dll is a DLL or OCX file, then try again*. I checked and the file mydocs.dll is present on my system32 folder. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

After years of frustrations, I believe that I may have found one solution. Start a terminal with Start: Run: **cmd**, then move to the folder containing the one to be removed (e.g., *My Videos*) with **CD** (e.g., *cd c:\users\me*), then use **RMDIR /S videos**. The *S* option allows to remove all the files contained in a directory as well as the folder itself. These folders are not really folders, but JUNCTIONs (see @RonK answer); with /S, you delete the folder as well as the linked folder (which otherwise is not visible).

I finally understood after having "Access denied" error messages. Although I was the owner of the *My Videos* folder, it could not be removed because, in fact, due to the JUNCTION, it was not really empty. With the /S option, it got erased cleanly.

In my case, Windows Media Player was not involved because I had removed it a long time ago from my computer.

Comment: Well, as it turns out, after one day, the "My videos" folder reappeared... So I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm overworked, so don't have time to give you the answer; just some pointers - and will excuse it by claiming not to give you a fish, but to teach you to fish...

In XP, I would have used Tweak Xp, the PowerToy. Having said that, I wouldn't have deleted it, just redirected it to my `D:` drive (which is Data for me), or `D:\music`, `D:\photos`, etc.  The one that annoys me most is automatically installing to `C:\Program Files`, since I have only Windows on `C:` and my programs are on `P:` - for ease of reinstalling Windows.

Anyway - short answer - Google.

Medium answer - regedit.  Hit <kbd>[image] (Windows key)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `regedit` (and <kbd>Enter</kbd>), to edit the registry. Search for keys whose value is `C:\My Music`, etc... At this point, I can't say what happens if you delete them. Maybe Windows will recreate them, but you probably have your own personal choice of directories for photos/music/etc., so why not just change the values?

Comment: In XP and Vista it's a piece of cake to get rid of these folders forever (if you know how to edit Windows registry).  But the problem is in Windows 7 + Windows Media Player 12.  I googled for a solution, but I got none at the present time.  All solutions are for XP/Vista and WMP 11 or less.  They don't work with W7 + WMP 12.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folders from the library and then go to registry and find this path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders. Here you will see the values of these three folders MY Music, My Video and My Picture just delete them.

[Mydigitallife has a trick to delete the library from explorer](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/05/how-to-disable-and-remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorer/).

Also check out [How to open My computer or document by default in windows 7](http://www.mydigitallife.info/trick-to-open-computer-or-documents-as-default-instead-of-libraries-folder-with-windows-explorer-on-windows-7/).

Comment: I just want to mention that this solution does not work: the folders keep reappearing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Windows Media Center.
2. Go to the "Tasks" section.
3. Open "Settings" from the "Task" section.
4. Click "Media Libraries."
5. Select the type of media for which you wish to remove folders, such as "Music" or "Pictures." Click "Next."
6. Select the "Remove folders" option. Click "Next."
7. Remove the checkmark from the box next to each folder you wish to remove. Click "Next."
8. Click "Yes" to proceed with the changes. Click "Finish."

Comment: He mentions in his question that he tried th is already

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8, there seems to be an easy solution.  I navigated to the c:\users\me\my pictures folder and under the "Home" tab clicked on Properties.  There under the Location tab I entered "D:\Pictures" and hit Apply.  Windows asks if you want to move all the files in My Pictures to the new location, and will do it if you say yes.  When done hit OK and reboot.  Now the c:\users\me\my pictures folder has been replaced by c:\users\me\pictures in the Explorer listing but the actual file location when you click on it is d:\Pictures. QED.

Comment: The question was how to delete the folder. Your solution still has a folder in \users\me\ cluttering up the place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since WMPlayer keep returning the mentioned folders, I opted to disable WMP from my system. It is a program that I don't use since there is a lot of better programs to do media.

From what I read from your comments, at first I was thinking about disabling parts of the registry involving WMP, but that seems like a lot of work. So why not just disable WMP? It worked for me.

Start → Control Panel →  Programs →  Turn Windows Features On Or Off → Media Features → WMP.

By disabling WMP, it also disables WMCenter (doesn't matter to me).

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the version of Windows 7, and is probably not the best solution.

Have you tried deleting the folder(s) and then changing the folder permissions?

1.Right click on `c:\users\<myuser>`

2.Left click Properties

3.Left click the third tab, "Security"

Make sure that YOU still have full permissions, and change the permissions of any other groups to "read and execute", "list folder contents", and "read". You may have to apply this recursively, and allow inheritable permissions.

This might block more than Media Player creating folders, it may block other programs too.

Knowing which version of Windows 7 would help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is any way to stop the kludgy Windows Media Player from
recreating these folders.

So if using WMP is absolutely required, and if you just don't want to **see**
these folders, then there is a permanent solution :

1. Install [Sandboxie Freeware](http://filehippo.com/download_sandboxie/)
2. Delete these unwanted folders
3. Create a desktop shortcut to WMP using the
   [Sandboxie Windows Shell Integration](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?ConfigureMenu#shell).
   Sandboxie will cache any disk changes away in its virtual file system,
   so they are not physically cluttering up `c:\users`.
4. Always only start WMP by using this desktop shortcut
5. For computer folders that you really wish WMP to manage,
   add them to Sandboxie as exceptions for WMP, using its [Resource Access Settings](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?ResourceAccessSettings#overview).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just adjust and point those paths to your custom Media folders? Windows will continue to recreate them. You cannot win unless you nuke your windows and go with a Nix machine. Pointing those library paths to your custom folder will work to your advantage. By those being the first ones to show up, you can quickly select your media folder and not waste precious time or screen space.

http://www.faqforge.com/windows/relocate-library-folders-in-windows-7-and-windows-8/

Answer (score -1):

I have this same frusration, and while I can't delete the folders, I was able to "make them go away" by right-clicking on them, going into "properties" and ticking the "hidden" check box.  Now I simply don't see them anymore!  Since seeing them was really the most annoying part of it, that sorta-kinda solves the issue for me..  Hope this at least helps a bit.