# Prevent Windows 7 from creating the My Music, My Pictures, My Videos folders when logging in?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I delete permanently My Folders in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/297389/how-can-i-delete-permanently-my-folders-in-windows-7)

I do not wish to have the My Music, My Pictures, My Videos folders in my user home directory on Windows 7. I tried deleting the folders, as well, as their corresponding values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`, but the next time I log in, they are created. How can I prevent Windows 7 from creating these folders?

Comment: You can move them away if you don't want them stay there. So your user home directory won't have them, but apps that require their location (as default saving/opening location) still works

Answer (score -1):

How to move Windows 7 folders

http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/05/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Ramhound Again, users with less than 50 reputation can not post comments. While this doesn't excuse a link-only or bad answer, please don't post these kinds of comments. Rather explain to people how to improve their answer. Thanks!